# How to install rJava package in Mac with M1 architecture

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava

I have a terrible time installing the package in R while I am using a Mac with M1 architecture.

Here are the steps I have followed so far

1. install Java https://www.azul.com/downloads/?os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk, using the version Zulu: 16.30.19
2. `install.packages("rJava")` in R
3. `R CMD javareconf` in terminal
4. `dyn.load("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib")` in R
5. `library(rJava)`

This is my error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jvm, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any help is be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

- Install the latest stable version of R from CRAN (tested on 4.3.1
  (2023-06-16))
- Install a x86_64 build of Java (version 17 - it does
  not seem to work with versions 8 or 11) with `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions && brew install --cask temurin17`
- Add it to PATH with `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)`
- run `sudo -E R CMD javareconf`

Then open R and `install.packages('rJava')` should work

Comment: Savior! This worked in R 4.3.2, macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (Mac Studio)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you but managed to get it going after finding this burried in some documetation.

> To use Java (specifically, package rJava) with a CRAN (‘x86_64’) binary distribution of R on ‘arm64’ macOS install a ‘x86_64’ build of a Java JRE such as that from AdoptOpenJDK, then run sudo R CMD javareconf.

> To see what compatible versions of Java are currently installed, run /usr/libexec/java_home -V -a x86_64. If needed, set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to choose between these, both when R is built from the sources and when R CMD javareconf is run.

> Configuring and building R both looks for a JRE and for support for compiling JNI programs (used to install packages rJava and JavaGD); the latter requires a JDK (Java SDK) and not just a JRE99.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html

Comment: A god send. Downloading the arm64 version of R 4.1.2 (from CRAN) and installing over the x86_64 version solved this issue.

Comment: @Levon Rush, could you transform this response into a step-by-step tutorial? Sorry, I couldn't follow it through, but I think this is exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The way I got things working well enough to use the packages I needed (e.g., `tabulizer`--see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381999/2620381)) was by backing all the way down to Java 8. To get a matching arm64 build, this means [getting Java from Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&package=jdk), since Oracle doesn't (yet?) put out one for that version.

Comment: This REALLY helped. I had installed Java 11 through conda. Downgrading to Java 8, running `R CMD javareconf` and re-installing rJava worked for me!