# How to resolve Java error when extracting tables from pdf using Tabulizer in R

Tags: java, r, pdf, error-handling, tabulizer

I'm trying to extract tables from a `pdf` using the `tabulizer` package in `R`. I run the following line:

```
table <- extract_tables('https://fm.dk/media/17137/oekonomisk-redegoerelse-august-2019_weba.pdf', pages = 20)
```

However I keep getting this error:

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
> cl,  :    java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class RJavaTools cannot
> access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$Itr (in module java.base)
> with modifiers "public"

I'm able to extract metadata from the `pdf`, so I'm pretty certain it is not problem with the installation of the `tabulizer` package, but more a java problem, which I'm not very experienced.

Comment: Sounds like problem with dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got this figured out, at least on my machine.  With [this hint](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/136#issuecomment-913003555) from [swsoyee](https://github.com/swsoyee) to a [sort-of similar open issue](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/136) on `tabulizer`'s GitHub page, I backed all the way down to Java 8.  On the new MBPs, this means [getting Java from Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&package=jdk), since Oracle doesn't (yet?) put out an arm64 build for that version.

I'm sure [there's a more elegant way](https://www.jenv.be), but I don't use Java otherwise, so I [trashed all the other Java versions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F) I'd installed before installing `zulu-8.jdk`.  (I also had to [trash the plugin](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html), but ymmv).  That did the trick:

```r
library(tabulizer)
table <- extract_tables('https://fm.dk/media/17137/oekonomisk-redegoerelse-august-2019_weba.pdf', pages = 20)
table[[1]]
#>       [,1]                                                             [,2]  
#>  [1,] "Tabel 1.1"                                                      ""    
#>  [2,] "Centrale skøn vedrørende tilrettelæggelsen af finanspolitikken" ""    
#>  [3,] "2018"                                                           "2019"
#>  [4,] "Strukturel saldo, pct. af strukturelt BNP 0,2"                  "-0,1"
#>  [5,] "Faktisk saldo, pct. af BNP 0,6"                                 "1,9" 
#>  [6,] "ØMU-gæld, pct. af BNP 34,1"                                     "33,7"
#>  [7,] "Offentlig forbrugsvækst, pct.1) 0,7"                            "0,8" 
#>  [8,] "Ét-årig finanseffekt, pct. af BNP2) -0,2"                       "-0,1"
#>  [9,] "Outputgab, pct.3) 0,1"                                          "0,8" 
#> [10,] "Beskæftigelsesgab, pct.3) 0,2"                                  "0,7" 
#>       [,3]  
#>  [1,] ""    
#>  [2,] ""    
#>  [3,] "2020"
#>  [4,] "0,0" 
#>  [5,] "0,4" 
#>  [6,] "33,5"
#>  [7,] "0,7" 
#>  [8,] "0,0" 
#>  [9,] "1,0" 
#> [10,] "0,9"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>