# Extract table from PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf, rjava, tabulizer

I am new to R and I want to extract data from a PDF.
Some context, I have followed a [tutorial](https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/) to setup rJava and then tried to run the code:

```
pacman::p_load(
  rJava,
  tabulizer,
  tidyverse)

Df <- extract_tables(
  file   = "C:/Users/afons/Epidemiology2021/BOLETIM EPIDEMIOLÓGICO COVID_FMV_26Julho-8Agosto2021.pdf", 
  method = "decide", 
  output = "data.frame")
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class RJavaTools cannot access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$Itr (in module java.base) with modifiers "public"
```

What could be causing this? It's a 3 Page PDF with a table on the page number 2 with header

Please help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381999/2620381

Comment: Could you provide a PDF file for which you want to extract some tables?