# Error with extract_tables function when running in it in a jupyter-notebook but not in console

Tags: java, r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, tabulizer

```
library(tabulizer)
f <- system.file("examples", "data.pdf", package = "tabulizer")
f1 <-  extract_tables(f,output = "data.frame")
f1[[1]]
```

Running the previous R command in a jupyter-notebook at VSCode outputs the error:

> ERROR: Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;",
> "invokeMethod", cl, : java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class
> RJavaTools cannot access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$Itr (in
> module java.base) with modifiers "public" Error in
> .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, :
> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class RJavaTools cannot access a
> member of class java.util.ArrayList$Itr (in module java.base) with
> modifiers "public" Traceback:
>
> 1. extract_tables(f, output = "data.frame")
> 2. guessesIterator$hasNext()
> 3. .jrcall(x, name, ...)
> 4. .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,   .     .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o, "jarrayRef")) o else
>    cl,   .         "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/String",
>    method),   .     j_p, j_pc, use.true.class = TRUE, evalString =
>    simplify,   .     evalArray = FALSE)
> 5. .jcheck(silent = FALSE)

But not when running in the R console.

Thanks in advance.

*I am running Java 11 (I also tried the 17 version, but the problem remains)

Comment: Welp, you're a step ahead of me: I get the same error also in the console on my arm64 MBP running R 4.1.2, rJava 1.0-6, Java jdk-17.0.1.jdk, and tabulizer 0.2.2.

Comment: Okay, I got this figured out, at least on my machine.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381999/2620381